# Samsung Galaxy S II won't start

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I shut down my phone last night like I always do. I went to start it up the next morning and it wouldn't boot. I knew the battery was at least half charged but I put it on the charger anyway. I didn't get the screen I usually do when I put the phone on the charger while it is shut down. I took out and replaced the battery. I don't know what else to do. All I have is a black screen. The user manual is useless. Any suggestions or should I just go to the T-Mobile store where I bought it?
Thanks!

Comment: Does *anything* happen when you press the power key? What about booting into other modes (safe mode, recovery)? How far does it get? Any activity like screen/LED flash, vibrate, ...?